# Closing the activity after clicking positive button in alert dialog in android

Tags: android

i have activity called "A" which displays the list of items.On clicking update button it shows the custom dialog (activity is showed in the back)with the list of items selected.When Order button inside custom dialog is clicked .

1. Custom dialog disappears.
2. progress dialog is showed(since order working is going on)
3. then progress dialog is closed after the order work is done
4. i ll show the alert dialog saying "Order confirmed"
5. When i click the positive button in alert dialog i want to close the activity which in the back(ie Activity A).Want to move to Home screen
6. How can i call the finish code inside the alertdialog positive button Onclicklistener()

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

```
noData.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
```

How can i add the finish() after cancelling the alertDialog()

Answer (score 13):

You'll need something like this:

```
noData.setPositiveButton("Ok",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Finish activity
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Just adding finish() inside the onClick should do the trick.

Comment: i think your suggestion will not help me close the current activity running .First i ll close the alertdialog and i want to close the current activity at the back

Comment: This is what finish does, there is no need to even close the dialog as this will be done when the activity is stopped.

Comment: This is a good suggestion if your `onClickListener` is an inner class of your activity A. `AlertDialog` will be closed anyway w/o any additional code.

Comment: i have the alertdialog inside the custom dialog class.finish() cant be added there.Scenario is i have an activity that calls the Custom dialog.On clicking the button in the custom dialog,dialog disappers then progress dialog starts then alertdialog with "Order confirmed" will open after the progress dialog stops.Now if i click on the Ok button in alertdialog i want to close the activity A which is still alive.I know it is little confusing.But kindly provide a solution

Comment: Just call `finish()` of your activity! It would be exactly `finish();` if your listener is an inner class of your activivty or `yourActivty.finish();` otherwise. If you still have no solution for your problem you can post your activity and listener code

Comment: It looks like you're using a dialog builder? I suggest you post more code as it's not clear what you're trying to do. There is absolutely no problem calling finish() within a dialog onClickListener.

Comment: you cannot just do `yourActivity.finish()` because `finish()` is not a static function. Check my answer below... this is just java.

Comment: This gives me a leaked window. Doesn't crash though. The dialog needs to be closed itself first before finish is called.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem as Mark.

Comment: You can just call `dialog.dismiss()` then before `finish()`. I rarely use dialogs and don't recall an issue with leaked windows.

Comment: Again, this only works if the alert is an inner class of the activity.

Answer (score 6):

See the code below (replace `MyActivity` with the name of your activity that this code is living in):

```
noData.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        MyActivity.this.finish();
}
});
```

Adding `this` is very important!

Comment: should i need to call dialog.dismiss or not while finishing activity from alert dialog positive button

Answer (score 0):

best option is to go with Handler. here is the reference link https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html

Comment: the worst option is to go with the Handler, the reason being that between handler.sendMessage and the handler acting on it, the looper will start running and your app will continue.