# AlertDialog, kill activity onClick "NO"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing the activity after clicking positive button in alert dialog in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388017/closing-the-activity-after-clicking-positive-button-in-alert-dialog-in-android)

it should be quite easy for some of you. Here is my little snippet:

```
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, (android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener) yesHandler)
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, //what now?)
```

these are the functions of my YES and NO alertdialog buttons. What should i place instead of "//what now?" for close the app activity?

Comment: You have a variable `yesHandler` and are casting it into an `OnClickListener`, are you sure that yesHandler implements `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an `OnClickListener` where you can call `finish()` for your activity.

```
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //replace MainActivity with your activity's name
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` on the Activity.

Comment: `finish()` isn't a listener, you should expand a bit on your answer.